# How can I convert a WARC file to a single page HTML file?

Tags: warc

Is there a way to convert a WARC file to a single page HTML file similar to the end result of what [monolith](https://github.com/Y2Z/monolith) or [SingleFile](https://github.com/gildas-lormeau/SingleFile) produce?